# Quantos dias tem o mês atual com Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria de saber quantos dias tem o mês atual com Javascript, por exemplo com PHP, eu faria assim:

```
Date('t');
```

Muito simples com PHP, mas e com Javascript tem algum jeito fácil?

Obs. eu uso AngularJS caso ajude em alguma coisa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function diasNoMes(mes, ano) {
    var data = new Date(ano, mes, 0);
    return data.getDate();
}

// Exemplo:
console.log(diasNoMes(2, 2017)); // Exibe 28.
```

Comment: Funcionou pq em JS o 2 é o mês três, e você pegou o ultimo dia do mes anterior. Precisa tomar cuidado com isso, se a pessoa usar com outras funções de JS que retornem o mês com base zero.

Comment: Como o @Bacco disse, é bom tomar cuidado quando se usa com um mês gerado pelo método `Date().getMonth();`. Se for o caso, o esquema é usar `var data = new Date(ano, mes + 1, 0);` ao invés disso.

Answer (score 4):

```js
function _numDias(){
  var objData = new Date(),
      numAno = objData.getFullYear(),
      numMes = objData.getMonth()+1,
      numDias = new Date(numAno, numMes, 0).getDate();

  return numDias;
}

console.log(_numDias());
```

Answer (score 2):

Retorna o numero de dias do mês em curso. Este mês de fevereiro de 2017 retorna 28. Mês de março 31 e assim por diante. Fevereiros bisextos retornarão 29.

```js
Date.prototype.diasNoCorrenteMes = function() {
  var days = [30, 31],
  m = this.getMonth();

  if (m == 1) {
    return ( (this.getFullYear() % 4 == 0) && ( (this.getFullYear() % 100 != 0 ) || (this.getFullYear() % 400 == 0) ) ) ? 29 : 28;
  } else {
    return days[(m + (m < 7 ? 1 : 0)) % 2];
  }
}

var myDate = new Date();

console.log(myDate.diasNoCorrenteMes());
```

Comment: Acredito que se você utilizar o [Ideone](https://ideone.com/) ou o [Repl.it](https://repl.it) para exibir seus códigos em funcionamento  terá melhores resultados. Se for apenas HTML/CSS/JS, pode utilizar a própria ferramenta do Stack Overflow.

Comment: Valeu Anderson Carlos Woss, ainda não descobri como fazer isso, sou novato!

Comment: Tem um erro aí, anos múltiplos de 100 não sao bissextos, a não ser que sejam múltiplos de 400 também. Só fazer % 4 não basta.

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ano_bissexto#Algoritmo_de_determina.C3.A7.C3.A3o

Comment: Bacco em 2100 estaremos todos no céu, rs. Será que isso tá correto? return this.getFullYear() % 4 == 0 && this.getFullYear() % 100 != 0 || this.getFullYear() % 400 == 0 ? 29 : 28;